# How do I return a generic type in Swift in a class that I am subclassing

Tags: ios, swift, generics, inheritance

I'm getting an error that I don't understand.  Any help would be appreciated.

I want to override a BaseViewController class and return a subclass of TableViewHandler like so

```
class VenueViewController: BaseViewController {

    override func tableHandler<T : TableViewHandler>() -> T? {
        return VenuesTableViewHandler(delegate: self) // Error here VenuesTableViewHandler is not convertible to 'T'
    }

}
```

This is what my BaseViewController looks like

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

    var tableViewHandler: AnyObject! {
        get {
            return self.tableHandler()
        }
    }

    func tableHandler<T: TableViewHandler >() -> T? {
        return nil
    }
}
```

I am getting error 'VenuesTableViewHandler is not convertible to 'T''. If it helps, this is what a TableViewHandler class looks like.

TableViewHandler is a class like so

```
class TableViewHandler: NSObject, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            return 0
    }

    ///etc

}
```

An this is what a TableViewHandler subclass looks like

```
class VenuesTableViewHandler: TableViewHandler {

    init(delegate: VenueListProtocol) {
        self.delegate = delegate
        super.init()
    }

}
```

Comment: What is `TableViewHandler`? A class or a protocol? In your example `VenuesTableViewHandler` does not have an initializer that takes a `delegate`. Maybe it could help if you show how `TableViewHandler` is intended to be.

Comment: It's a class. Updated my question.

Comment: Have you tried `typealias T = VenuesTableViewHandler`?

Comment: I want a type 'T' which is a subclass of TableViewHandler. Not just a type named 'VenuesTableViewHandler'.

Comment: Why you want to use generics in tableHandler? Will just a polymorphic method do the job for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still non completely clear what you are trying, does the following conform to your needs?

```
class TableViewHandler: NSObject, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 0
    }

    ///etc

}

class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

    var tableViewHandler: TableViewHandler {
        get {
            assertionFailure("Must override ...")
            //return TableViewHandler()
        }
    }
}

class VenuesTableViewHandler: TableViewHandler {
    init(delegate: AnyObject) {
        // Custom implementation
    }
}

class VenueViewController: BaseViewController {

    override var tableViewHandler: TableViewHandler {
        return VenuesTableViewHandler(delegate: self)
    }
}
```

Notice here I do not use *generics* at all.